# INT type to quarter in SQL

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have data that I am trying to transform in a quarter interval;
The data it's stored as INT in this format:

```
202001
202002
202004
```

Desired results: 202001 - Q1, 202004 - Q2

Comment: You shouldn't be doing date formatting in SQL. This should be done in your application code.

Comment: Also, storing any kind of _formatted date_ value as an integer is terrible. You need to go slap whoever designed your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to a date, then then get the Quater

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(202001)
,(202002)
,(202004)

Select *
      ,NewValue = concat(SomeCol,' - Q',datepart(QUARTER,try_convert(date,left(SomeCol,6)+'01')))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol NewValue
202001  202001 - Q1
202002  202002 - Q1
202004  202004 - Q2
```